# Helm range with 2 variables

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

im trying to a loop with a range in helm but using 2 variables, what i have..

**values.yaml**

```
master:
  slave1: 
    - slave1value1
    - slave1value2
  slave2: 
    - slave2value1
    - slave2value2
```

My actual loop.

```
{{- range  .Values.master.slave1 }}
        name: http://slave1-{{ . }}
{{- end }}
{{- range  .Values.master.slave2 }}
        name: http://slave2-{{ . }}
{{- end }}
```

This is actually doing what i need, the output will be like this...

looping on `.Values.master.slave1`

```
name: http://slave1-slave1value1
name: http://slave1-slave1value2
```

looping on `.Values.master.slave2`

```
name: http://slave2-slave1value1
name: http://slave2-slave1value2
```

This is fully working for now, the question is, can i achieve the same result using just one loop block ? i tried this.

```
{{ alias := .Values.master }}
{{- range  $alias }}
        name: http://{{ . }}-{{ $alias.name }}
{{- end }}
```

But the output is not what I'm expecting, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost...you need a nested loop to do this.  The top-level data structure is a map, where the keys are the worker names and the values are the list of values.  So you can iterate through the top-level map, then for each item iterate through the value list.

```
{{- $key, $values := range .Values.master -}}
{{- $value := range $values -}}
name: http://{{ $key }}-{{ $value }}
{{ end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Note that we've assigned the values of `range` to locals to avoid some ambiguity around what exactly `.` means (inside each `range` loop it would be the iterator, for the currently-innermost loop).

Comment: Hi @David Maze, i'm trying what you suggested but for some reason is not working, i'm getting this error. ```too many declarations in command```

Comment: That sounds like it could be an error in the context you're using this value.  You might try running `helm template` over your chart to see what it prints out.

Comment: The correct answer is the comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67745001/7354490.

Answer (score 4):

Hi @DavidMaze i made it work changing the order of the "range" in the loop.

This doesn't work.

```
{{- $key, $values := range .Values.master -}}
{{- $value := range $values -}}
name: http://{{ $key }}-{{ $value }}
{{ end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

This work as expected :)

```
{{- range $key, $values := .Values.master -}}
{{- range $value := $values -}}
name: http://{{ $key }}-{{ $value }}
{{ end -}}
{{- end -}}
```